# how to make @onpaste in a textarea trigger the v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a textarea that triggers a function whenever the space key is pressed, that function checks if the last "bit" of text entered is an url or not and if it is it creates a preview underneath and deletes the "bit" of text from the input, that works fine, but now I want too that function to be triggered whenever the user paste something into it, the problem is that the input is linked with v-model to `post.description` in the data, but when @paste calls the function the data `post.description` is empty but when the same function is triggered by pressing the space key that data is filled...
this is the html:

```
<div id="post-share" class="form-group">
                      <textarea
                        id="post-description"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="post-description"
                        cols="40"
                        rows="5"
                        @keyup.space="checkUrl"
                        @paste="checkUrl"
                        v-model="post.description"
                      ></textarea>
```

and this is the function:

```
   checkUrl() {
      if (this.post.video_link === "") {
        console.log("entro 1");
        let link = [];
        const regex = /((?:https?:|www\.)[^\s]+)/g;
        let url = this.post.description.match(regex);
        console.log(this.post.description);

        if (url) {
          console.log("entro 2");
          url.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            link = match.split("=");
            this.$set(this.post, "video_link", link[1]);
            this.is_there_url = true;
            this.post.description = this.post.description.replace(match, "");
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

so it does not meet the condition `if (url)` as this.post.description is empty... any hint why is only empty when trigerred by @paste and not when pressing space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe the @paste event is triggered before binding the value to `post.description`.

Try using a watcher instead

```
<textarea 
     id="post-description" 
     class="form-control"
     name="post-description"
     cols="40"
     rows="5"
     v-model="post.description"
></textarea>
```

and then in the script section add

```
computed:{
    postDescription(){
        return this.post.description
    }
},
watch: {
    postDescription() {
      this.checkUrl()
    }
}
```

I don't know the model you are trying to achieve but you have to add conditions on the watcher to prevent the execution of the method on every new character added to improve the performance.

Comment: thanks it works! I think I will review the docu on computed and watch as I am pretty new to Vue, as far as I understand thiss postDescription method will be executed every time the textarea changes? so everytime the user type something right?

Comment: Every time the user type something the value of post.description will change as will as the value of the computed property postDescription. And the watcher watches the postDescription computed property if it is changed it run the method. 
So basically this method is triggered on each character written by the user